# How to fix "vagrant up" errors when trying to set up Trellis?

Tags: wordpress, vagrant, virtualbox, trellis

I've been trying to set up a Trellis local WordPress dev environment from the Roots stack. I did all the [steps from the docs](https://roots.io/docs/trellis/master/installation/), have the recommended folder structure, downloaded all the dependencies, but I still get a few errors.

First I get some errors and warnings when I use "yarn" in my theme folder, as [suggested here](https://roots.io/docs/sage/9.x/installation/). They say to use the CLI from my host instead of Vagrant box, that's just the MacBook's terminal right? Or do I need a CLI from VirtualBox?

The second error happens when trying to call "vagrant up", and this is one that I can paste here as it's a bit more concise.

```
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

After Googling this I got a lot of outdated suggestions to check my PATH and restart the VirtualBox, but these I tried and didn't help. I hope someone can help me set this up, thanks. :)